# Write a recursive function which will calculate the sum of all numbers from 1 to n - swift

Tags: swift, recursion

What can I put in this function to calculate the sum of numbers from 1 to n in swift?

```
func sumOfNumbersRecursive(n: Int) -> Int {
    if (n == 0) {

    }
    else {          
        //recursive
    }
}
```

Thanks

Comment: I don't think you understand the concept of recursive functions.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
func sumOfNumbers(n: Int) -> Int {
    if (n == 0) {
       return 0
    }

    return sumOfNumbers(n - 1) + n
}
```

But there are easier ways to solve this in Swift, e.g.

```
let n = 10
let sum = (0 ... n).reduce(0, combine: +)
```

Comment: Or `let sum = (n + 1) * n / 2`